# Is there an easier/more efficient way to update values in this json file?

Tags: javascript, json, database, data-entry

So I have a tampermonkey script running. The script uses a json file where it stores specific filters. I have to manually update some values of these filters about three times a day. Now I'm left with this json file which looks kinda terrible and is a pain to edit I'll show a part of it below.

```
{
"data": {
    "DAVID SILVA RB HUNT": "s{\"searchCriteria\":{\"criteria\":{\"_acquiredDate\":\"\",\"_category\":\"any\",\"_position\":\"any\",\"_sort\":\"desc\",\"_type\":\"player\",\"_untradeables\":\"\",\"_zone\":-1,\"club\":-1,\"count\":21,\"defId\":[],\"excludeDefIds\":[],\"isExactSearch\":false,\"league\":-1,\"level\":\"any\",\"maskedDefId\":168542,\"maxBid\":0,\"maxBuy\":120000,\"minBid\":700,\"minBuy\":0,\"nation\":-1,\"offset\":0,\"playStyle\":266,\"rarities\":[6],\"sortBy\":\"value\",\"subtypes\":[]},\"playerData\":{\"id\":168542,\"firstName\":\"David Josué\",\"lastName\":\"Jiménez Silva\",\"commonName\":\"David Silva\",\"rating\":86}},\"abSettings\":{\"buyPrice\":\"119000\",\"sellPrice\":\"131000\",\"minDeleteCount\":\"50\",\"waitTime\":\"7-15\",\"maxPurchases\":\"1\",\"randMinBid\":\"2000\",\"useRandMinBid\":true,\"telegramBotToken\":\"1499673950:AAFI3vtBhZ72BlMlCbF5qdIp8cptoR_TeyI\",\"telegramChatID\":\"1253533225\",\"telegramBuy\":\"A\",\"notificationEnabled\":true,\"soundEnabled\":true}}",
    "DAVID SILVA RB SHADOW": "s{\"searchCriteria\":{\"criteria\":{\"_acquiredDate\":\"\",\"_category\":\"any\",\"_position\":\"any\",\"_sort\":\"desc\",\"_type\":\"player\",\"_untradeables\":\"\",\"_zone\":-1,\"club\":-1,\"count\":21,\"defId\":[],\"excludeDefIds\":[],\"isExactSearch\":false,\"league\":-1,\"level\":\"any\",\"maskedDefId\":168542,\"maxBid\":0,\"maxBuy\":120000,\"minBid\":650,\"minBuy\":0,\"nation\":-1,\"offset\":0,\"playStyle\":268,\"rarities\":[6],\"sortBy\":\"value\",\"subtypes\":[]},\"playerData\":{\"id\":168542,\"firstName\":\"David Josué\",\"lastName\":\"Jiménez Silva\",\"commonName\":\"David Silva\",\"rating\":86}},\"abSettings\":{\"buyPrice\":\"119000\",\"sellPrice\":\"131000\",\"minDeleteCount\":\"50\",\"waitTime\":\"7-15\",\"maxPurchases\":\"1\",\"randMinBid\":\"2000\",\"useRandMinBid\":true,\"telegramBotToken\":\"1499673950:AAFI3vtBhZ72BlMlCbF5qdIp8cptoR_TeyI\",\"telegramChatID\":\"1253533225\",\"telegramBuy\":\"A\",\"notificationEnabled\":true,\"soundEnabled\":true}}",
    "MAHREZ IF HUNT": "s{\"searchCriteria\":{\"criteria\":{\"_acquiredDate\":\"\",\"_category\":\"any\",\"_position\":\"any\",\"_sort\":\"desc\",\"_type\":\"player\",\"_untradeables\":\"\",\"_zone\":-1,\"club\":-1,\"count\":20,\"defId\":[],\"excludeDefIds\":[],\"isExactSearch\":false,\"league\":-1,\"level\":\"any\",\"maskedDefId\":204485,\"maxBid\":0,\"maxBuy\":117000,\"minBid\":0,\"minBuy\":0,\"nation\":-1,\"offset\":0,\"playStyle\":266,\"rarities\":[3],\"sortBy\":\"value\",\"subtypes\":[]},\"playerData\":{\"id\":204485,\"firstName\":\"Riyad\",\"lastName\":\"Mahrez\",\"commonName\":null,\"rating\":85}},\"abSettings\":{\"buyPrice\":\"113000\",\"sellPrice\":\"125000\",\"minDeleteCount\":\"50\",\"waitTime\":\"7-15\",\"maxPurchases\":\"1\",\"minRate\":\"86\",\"randMinBid\":\"2000\",\"useRandMinBid\":true,\"telegramBotToken\":\"1499673950:AAFI3vtBhZ72BlMlCbF5qdIp8cptoR_TeyI\",\"telegramChatID\":\"1253533225\",\"telegramBuy\":\"A\",\"notificationEnabled\":true,\"soundEnabled\":true}}",
    "MAHREZ IF SHADOW": "s{\"searchCriteria\":{\"criteria\":{\"_acquiredDate\":\"\",\"_category\":\"any\",\"_position\":\"any\",\"_sort\":\"desc\",\"_type\":\"player\",\"_untradeables\":\"\",\"_zone\":-1,\"club\":-1,\"count\":21,\"defId\":[],\"excludeDefIds\":[],\"isExactSearch\":false,\"league\":-1,\"level\":\"any\",\"maskedDefId\":204485,\"maxBid\":0,\"maxBuy\":117000,\"minBid\":1700,\"minBuy\":0,\"nation\":-1,\"offset\":0,\"playStyle\":268,\"rarities\":[3],\"sortBy\":\"value\",\"subtypes\":[]},\"playerData\":{\"id\":204485,\"firstName\":\"Riyad\",\"lastName\":\"Mahrez\",\"commonName\":null,\"rating\":85}},\"abSettings\":{\"buyPrice\":\"113000\",\"sellPrice\":\"125000\",\"minDeleteCount\":\"50\",\"waitTime\":\"7-15\",\"maxPurchases\":\"1\",\"minRate\":\"86\",\"randMinBid\":\"2000\",\"useRandMinBid\":true,\"telegramBotToken\":\"1499673950:AAFI3vtBhZ72BlMlCbF5qdIp8cptoR_TeyI\",\"telegramChatID\":\"1253533225\",\"telegramBuy\":\"A\",\"notificationEnabled\":true,\"soundEnabled\":true}}",
```

As I said this is only a part of it. It extends like this for about 200 lines. Per line I have to edit 3 values; "maxBuy", buyPrice" and "sellPrice". Because the file is formatted like this it takes so long. I've tried converting it to a csv to edit and then convert back to json but this didn't really work again because of the formatting I think.

Any tips on how to make it easier to edit these values would be highly appreciated!

edit: I've also tried to somehow tie the json file to a database for easier editing but yet again no luck. Then I tried editing it using python but couldn't seem to make it any more efficient than just going/scrolling through every line.

Comment: Do you mean to edit the file manually with a text editor as opposed to edit it programmatically with a piece of JavaScript code? I'd say the problem here isn't JSON but the custom (?) internal format. If you're already using JSON, why not use it all the way down?

Comment: If data is being generated via a script then the responsibility of updating it should also belong to a script. Manually you won't be able to catch up, it will time consuming and error prone too.

Comment: Im okay with doing it manually but as it isn't my script I don't have control over what the format looks like. It just outputs this file. If there is a way to edit using JS I'm all open for it. The thing I had in mind was something simple like opening it in excel then edit the specific values and save and convert back to json because the script uses the json file in that format if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

The data you provided is not a valid JSON. This is important, when you want to process it programmatically.

The snippet below

- converts the data into JSON
- displays a table for updating the data
- on a button click creates the original format with the updated values in a textarea

From the textarea you can copy the modified results back. I think this is more convenient than text modification.

```js
const d = {
  "data": {
    "DAVID SILVA RB HUNT": "s{\"searchCriteria\":{\"criteria\":{\"_acquiredDate\":\"\",\"_category\":\"any\",\"_position\":\"any\",\"_sort\":\"desc\",\"_type\":\"player\",\"_untradeables\":\"\",\"_zone\":-1,\"club\":-1,\"count\":21,\"defId\":[],\"excludeDefIds\":[],\"isExactSearch\":false,\"league\":-1,\"level\":\"any\",\"maskedDefId\":168542,\"maxBid\":0,\"maxBuy\":120000,\"minBid\":700,\"minBuy\":0,\"nation\":-1,\"offset\":0,\"playStyle\":266,\"rarities\":[6],\"sortBy\":\"value\",\"subtypes\":[]},\"playerData\":{\"id\":168542,\"firstName\":\"David Josué\",\"lastName\":\"Jiménez Silva\",\"commonName\":\"David Silva\",\"rating\":86}},\"abSettings\":{\"buyPrice\":\"119000\",\"sellPrice\":\"131000\",\"minDeleteCount\":\"50\",\"waitTime\":\"7-15\",\"maxPurchases\":\"1\",\"randMinBid\":\"2000\",\"useRandMinBid\":true,\"telegramBotToken\":\"1499673950:AAFI3vtBhZ72BlMlCbF5qdIp8cptoR_TeyI\",\"telegramChatID\":\"1253533225\",\"telegramBuy\":\"A\",\"notificationEnabled\":true,\"soundEnabled\":true}}",
    "DAVID SILVA RB SHADOW": "s{\"searchCriteria\":{\"criteria\":{\"_acquiredDate\":\"\",\"_category\":\"any\",\"_position\":\"any\",\"_sort\":\"desc\",\"_type\":\"player\",\"_untradeables\":\"\",\"_zone\":-1,\"club\":-1,\"count\":21,\"defId\":[],\"excludeDefIds\":[],\"isExactSearch\":false,\"league\":-1,\"level\":\"any\",\"maskedDefId\":168542,\"maxBid\":0,\"maxBuy\":120000,\"minBid\":650,\"minBuy\":0,\"nation\":-1,\"offset\":0,\"playStyle\":268,\"rarities\":[6],\"sortBy\":\"value\",\"subtypes\":[]},\"playerData\":{\"id\":168542,\"firstName\":\"David Josué\",\"lastName\":\"Jiménez Silva\",\"commonName\":\"David Silva\",\"rating\":86}},\"abSettings\":{\"buyPrice\":\"119000\",\"sellPrice\":\"131000\",\"minDeleteCount\":\"50\",\"waitTime\":\"7-15\",\"maxPurchases\":\"1\",\"randMinBid\":\"2000\",\"useRandMinBid\":true,\"telegramBotToken\":\"1499673950:AAFI3vtBhZ72BlMlCbF5qdIp8cptoR_TeyI\",\"telegramChatID\":\"1253533225\",\"telegramBuy\":\"A\",\"notificationEnabled\":true,\"soundEnabled\":true}}",
    "MAHREZ IF HUNT": "s{\"searchCriteria\":{\"criteria\":{\"_acquiredDate\":\"\",\"_category\":\"any\",\"_position\":\"any\",\"_sort\":\"desc\",\"_type\":\"player\",\"_untradeables\":\"\",\"_zone\":-1,\"club\":-1,\"count\":20,\"defId\":[],\"excludeDefIds\":[],\"isExactSearch\":false,\"league\":-1,\"level\":\"any\",\"maskedDefId\":204485,\"maxBid\":0,\"maxBuy\":117000,\"minBid\":0,\"minBuy\":0,\"nation\":-1,\"offset\":0,\"playStyle\":266,\"rarities\":[3],\"sortBy\":\"value\",\"subtypes\":[]},\"playerData\":{\"id\":204485,\"firstName\":\"Riyad\",\"lastName\":\"Mahrez\",\"commonName\":null,\"rating\":85}},\"abSettings\":{\"buyPrice\":\"113000\",\"sellPrice\":\"125000\",\"minDeleteCount\":\"50\",\"waitTime\":\"7-15\",\"maxPurchases\":\"1\",\"minRate\":\"86\",\"randMinBid\":\"2000\",\"useRandMinBid\":true,\"telegramBotToken\":\"1499673950:AAFI3vtBhZ72BlMlCbF5qdIp8cptoR_TeyI\",\"telegramChatID\":\"1253533225\",\"telegramBuy\":\"A\",\"notificationEnabled\":true,\"soundEnabled\":true}}",
    "MAHREZ IF SHADOW": "s{\"searchCriteria\":{\"criteria\":{\"_acquiredDate\":\"\",\"_category\":\"any\",\"_position\":\"any\",\"_sort\":\"desc\",\"_type\":\"player\",\"_untradeables\":\"\",\"_zone\":-1,\"club\":-1,\"count\":21,\"defId\":[],\"excludeDefIds\":[],\"isExactSearch\":false,\"league\":-1,\"level\":\"any\",\"maskedDefId\":204485,\"maxBid\":0,\"maxBuy\":117000,\"minBid\":1700,\"minBuy\":0,\"nation\":-1,\"offset\":0,\"playStyle\":268,\"rarities\":[3],\"sortBy\":\"value\",\"subtypes\":[]},\"playerData\":{\"id\":204485,\"firstName\":\"Riyad\",\"lastName\":\"Mahrez\",\"commonName\":null,\"rating\":85}},\"abSettings\":{\"buyPrice\":\"113000\",\"sellPrice\":\"125000\",\"minDeleteCount\":\"50\",\"waitTime\":\"7-15\",\"maxPurchases\":\"1\",\"minRate\":\"86\",\"randMinBid\":\"2000\",\"useRandMinBid\":true,\"telegramBotToken\":\"1499673950:AAFI3vtBhZ72BlMlCbF5qdIp8cptoR_TeyI\",\"telegramChatID\":\"1253533225\",\"telegramBuy\":\"A\",\"notificationEnabled\":true,\"soundEnabled\":true}}",
  }
}

// transforming source data format to JSON
const getJSON = (source) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(d.data).map(([key, val]) => {
    return [key, JSON.parse(val.replace(/^s/, ''))]
  }))
}

// writing source data format
const writeObject = (json) => {
  const data = {}
  for (let key in json) {
    data[key] = 's' + JSON.stringify(json[key])
  }
  return {
    data
  }
}

// table row template
const tableRow = ({
  key,
  maxBuy,
  buyPrice,
  sellPrice
}) => {
  html = ''
  html += `
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        ${ key }
      </td>
      <td>maxBuy</td>
      <td>${ maxBuy }</td>
      <td>
        <input
          data-updateid="${ key },maxBuy"
          type="number"
          value="${ maxBuy }"
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>buyPrice</td>
      <td>${ buyPrice }</td>
      <td>
        <input
          data-updateid="${ key },buyPrice"
          type="number"
          value="${ buyPrice }"
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sellPrice</td>
      <td>${ sellPrice }</td>
      <td>
        <input
          data-updateid="${ key },sellPrice"
          type="number"
          value="${ sellPrice }"
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  `
  return html
};

(function(json) {
  // deep copying the source
  let newJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json))

  // creating the rows in the table
  let html = ''
  for (let key in json) {
    const {
      searchCriteria: {
        criteria: {
          maxBuy
        }
      },
      abSettings: {
        buyPrice,
        sellPrice
      }
    } = json[key]
    const rowData = {
      key,
      maxBuy,
      buyPrice,
      sellPrice
    }
    html += tableRow(rowData)
  }
  // setting rows of the tbody
  const tableBody = document.querySelector('#table tbody')
  tableBody.innerHTML = html

  // setting up input action (update)
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
      // setting up received data
      const {
        target: {
          value: val,
          dataset
        }
      } = e
      const [key, dataid] = dataset['updateid'].split(',')

      // the newJSON is updated here
      if (dataid === 'maxBuy') {
        newJSON[key].searchCriteria.criteria.maxBuy = val
      } else {
        newJSON[key].abSettings[dataid] = val
      }
    })
  })

  // modal handling
  const backdrop = document.getElementById('backdrop')
  backdrop.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('show')
  })
  const modal = document.getElementById('modal')
  modal.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
  })

  // create new object & display it in the modal
  const btnGetNewObject = document.getElementById('getNewObject')
  btnGetNewObject.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const tocopy = document.getElementById('tocopy')
    tocopy.value = JSON.stringify(writeObject(newJSON))
    backdrop.classList.add('show')
  })
})(getJSON(d));
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table tr th,
table tr td {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

#backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#backdrop.show {
  display: flex;
}

#modal {
  padding: 16px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="getNewObject">GET NEW OBJECT</button><br /><br />
<hr />
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <th>
      KEY
    </th>
    <th>
      VARIABLE
    </th>
    <th>
      SOURCE VALUE
    </th>
    <th>
      NEW VALUE
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="backdrop">
  <div id="modal">
    <textarea id="tocopy" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for. Looks like this is totally above my head as I don't even know how to run this locally to make it work. I guess I've got loads of homework!

Comment: @OliverMulder you could just paste it in an HTML (locally) or create JsFiddle/Codepen snippet & change the input when you want to run it. I’m glad that I could help!

Comment: Yes thanks I figured it out! It's an absolute god gift you put together.

Comment: @OliverMulder with lots of items it may get slow. The same thing with a Vue application is shorter, faster - just didn’t want to complicate that for you with a framework :)

Comment: Oh I'm really excited to learn more about this all. Is there some documentation you can link me to read up on it?

Comment: @OliverMulder tons-and-tons. But I would suggest starting at [vuejs.org](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) (Vue2) or [Vue3 guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html). But you could also work with React, Svelte, etc - any modern reactive framework will do the trick :) If you look at **Install** chapters, you'll see that it's not hard to set up a project for yourself

Comment: @OliverMulder or look up some beginners course on Youtube - I like this guy's course: [Vue.JS Fundamentals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRJo_TXdqPg) - he has a course on Udemy too (that's not for free).

Comment: Thanks will check it all out. Looking forward to learn!